# If I remember reading a book but don't have it in front of me to quote from, is it worth writing an answer?

Tags: discussion, quotations

I use the library a lot. This means that I often read books that I later no longer have access to.

There have been times when someone has asked a question about a book that I read but no longer have access to. Is it worth writing an answer based on what I remember about the book?

Comment: I think the answer to this question should be obvious, but I'm upvoting it anyway as it might be something new users often wonder and therefore a post worth pointing them to in the future.

Answer (score 9):

### It can be, yes.

If you know a book well, then you should still be able to write a good answer even without remembering all the relevant quotes verbatim. That's called an **expert answer** - you're writing as a person with some level of expertise on the book in question, not just as someone who has an electronic copy with a search facility.

Of course, that doesn't mean all quoteless answers are good. "*I remember Character X said something about Y, which probably means the answer to your question is yes*" would be a bad answer, but "*Character X confirms that Y is true, in Chapter 17 just after Z happens; this means the answer is yes*" might be almost as good as providing the actual quote from Chapter 17.